# How do I maintain image size when using a colorbar?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot, colorbar

I'm trying to plot two versions of the same image side by side. When I plot the figure without the color bar for one of the images, it seems to have the right sizes:

[image: without the color bar]

But when I add a color bar to the image in the left, it scales the image down somehow:

[image: scales the image down]

Here's the code where I have commented out the lines for color bar:

```
def plot_amaps(self, anisotropy_map, parallel):
        timepoint = self.t * self.timestep
        amap_directory = self.directory + "amaps/"
        fig = plt.figure(facecolor='w', dpi=180)

        ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
        fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)
        ax1.grid(False)
        txt = "Mean(r) = %.3f SD(r)= %.3f t=%dmin"
        txt = txt %(self.mean, self.sd, timepoint)
        ax1.set_title(txt)

        amap = ax1.imshow(anisotropy_map, cmap="jet", clim = self.clim)
        #divider = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
        #cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)
        #fig.colorbar(amap, cax=cax)

        ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
        ax2.set_title("Intensity image", fontsize=10)
        ax2.imshow(parallel, cmap="gray")
        ax2.grid(False)
        ax1.axis('off')
        ax2.axis('off')

        if self.save is True:
            self.make_plot_dir(amap_directory)
            name = self.cell + "_time_"+str(timepoint)
            plt.savefig(amap_directory+name+self.saveformat, bbox_inches='tight')
        else:
            plt.show()
        plt.close('all')
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I make sure that the two images are of the same size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using

```
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)
```

you explicitely ask for a 5% smaller axes. So if you don't want that, you should not create the axes for the colorbar using `make_axes_locatable`.

Instead you can simply create an axes at any point on the figure using

```
cax = fig.add_axes([left, bottom, width, height])
```

where `left, bottom, width, height` are in figure units ranging from 0 to 1. Then add the colorbar to it.
If you want the colorbar in the middle, you could previously make some space using

```
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3)
```

Of course you would have to experiment a bit with the numbers.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `append_axes()` it actually reduces the size of `ax1` to make room for the colormap.
If you want to make sure the size of your axes don't change, you should create them explicitly.
Here is my attempt:

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,3,width_ratios=[5,1,5])
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='w', dpi=180)

randomData = np.random.random(size=(100,100))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
ax1.grid(False)
txt = "Mean(r) = %.3f SD(r)= %.3f t=%dmin"
txt = txt %(0, 0, 0)
ax1.set_title(txt)

amap = ax1.imshow(randomData, cmap="jet")
#divider = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
#cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)
fig.colorbar(amap, cax=fig.add_subplot(gs[1]))

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2])
ax2.set_title("Intensity image", fontsize=10)
ax2.imshow(randomData, cmap="gray")
ax2.grid(False)
ax1.axis('off')
ax2.axis('off')
```

[image]

Comment: Dumb question: how can I reduce the size of the colorbar? `fig.colorbar(amap, cax=fig.add_subplot(gs[1]), shrink=.5)` returns an error.

Comment: do you mean vertical size, or horizontal size. For horizontal size, you can change the `width_ratios` in the creation of the GridSpec. I did `[5,1,5]` which means that the images are 5x the size of the colorbar, but you could adjust according to your need. For vertical, I'm not sure, I saw that my solution provides a much bigger scale than your desired output. There is probably some options on padding that can be passed when creating the Axes, or see the answer by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest where you directly specify the size of the axes.